# Cannot start Ubuntu: endlessly shows running Ubuntu logo

Tags: ubuntu

I can't start my computer anymore (nothing changed). It shows the Ubuntu-logo with the five white dots becoming red and white again, endlessly. No error, no login screen.

Anybody any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could potentially be a lot of different issues As a starting point you'll want to Boot into a command line mode. As an penultimate troubleshooting step you could boot into single user mode, which will be a root level, no network access, minimal start process mode.

Generally speaking this is accomplished by highlighting your os/kernal value in grub, and pressint E to edit it

usually there will be a set of lines that look similar to:

> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=bc6f8146-1523-46a6-8b\ 
>   6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash 
>   initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic

You'll want to add the word "single" to the end of the middle line. IE:

> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=bc6f8146-1523-46a6-8b\ 
>   6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash single 
>   initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic

then press ctrl-x to boot. This should boot you to a root console that you can examine logs and potentially see any other errors in the startup process.

Alternatively....Looking at some information(i haven't used ubuntu specifically in a while)

The line changes might need to be the following:

> linux     /vmlinuz-2.6.32-40-server root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--base--chef-root ro quiet splash

TO

> linux     /vmlinuz-2.6.32-40-server root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--base--chef-root rw init=/bin/bash

Essentially you are changing ro quiet splash, to rw init=/bin/bash

Comment: Thanks a lot. This gave me a "failed command: READ DMA" error mesasage. Now I'am trying to fix this by using a bootable ubuntu-usb-stick. Hope this will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/321277/how-do-i-recover-from-a-read-dma-bootup-error

Answer (score 0):

The message `failed command: READ DMA` usually means broken hard drive hardware.

I believe that `quiet` and `splash` are inappropriate defaults for server distro, so I always remove them from kernel boot command line. Server admins won't rather be scared by a stream of boot messages, and the default of no-splash may sometimes alert you of unusual circumstances. To get rid of splash screen:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure grub2-pc
```

...and in your kernel command line replace `splash` and `quiet` with just `nosplash`.

Comment: I did a complete reinstall of Ubuntu and now it works fine (as far as I can see). SMART Data & Self-Tests now gives "Disk is OK, 58 bad sectors"

Comment: And `badblocks` gives 12 (??)

Comment: S.M.A.R.T. reads the number of (possibly masked) bad blocks from disk firmware, and `badblocks` only reports the ones visible to OS. I believe even a **single** bad sector not masked by firmware qualifies a server hard drive to be replaced immediately, except when you're really brave.